# Unable to connect to nodejs server on raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I am attempting to build a nodejs app on raspberry pi 2. I am having an issue with connecting to the nodejs server. I keep getting "Could not connect: Connection refused" when I try to connect via localhost or remotely from my mac (192.168.1.151:8080) not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Code from my server.js file.

```
var express = require('express'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
http = require('http'),
app = {},
server = {};



// Create instance of application
app = express();

// Create server instance
server = http.createServer(app);

// Entry point into app
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.html', function(err, res){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log(res);
        }
    })
});

// Run app on port 3000
server.listen('8080', function(){
    var host = server.address().address,
        port = server.address().port;

    console.log('Vudu Home Automation listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Results from running sudo netstat -vltn:
Active Internet connections (only servers)

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:548             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5901            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1883            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::1883                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:4700                :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: I should restate the connections part. I connect to the pi via ssh so the part about viewing the app via localhost is actually remote as well via ssh.

Comment: First, you should establish whether you have network connectivity to your raspberry pi.  Can you do "ping 192.168.1.151" from the computer that you're trying to connect from?  Then, can you verify that the server is running on the pi?

Comment: It would appear that I can ping 192.168.1.151. 

20 packets transmitted, 20 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.982/4.561/16.925/3.357 ms

Comment: OK, you have connectivity to the server.  Now you need to figure out why the server process isn't responding either on the server to localhost or from your mac to the IP address.  From the terminal on the PI, can you verify that the server process is alive and listening on the desired port?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but how would I do that?  :)

Comment: From your PI terminal, do `netstat -vltn` and it will show you listening sockets.

Comment: I seems it's not running?

Comment: I can't put the results here as it is to many characters but there seems to be no process listening on port 8080.

Comment: I don't know if this matters or not, but ports are numbers, not strings so `server.listen('8080')` should be `server.listen(8080)`.

Comment: For reference, my raspberry pi that is listening on port 8081 shows `tcp        0   0 0.0.0.0:8081    0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN` for the same `netstat -vltn`.
` so there does appear to be an issue with your server starting properly.

Comment: I changed '8080' to just 8080. That didn't work. I would agree that the server isn't starting just not sure how to resolve the issue.  :(

Comment: Add a server error handler before you call `server.listen()` to see if anything is emitted there: `server.on('error', function(e)  {console.log(e)});`

Comment: No luck. Doesn't throw an err.

Comment: And, you put that error handler BEFORE you called `.listen()`?

Comment: Sure did. I have just been trying to catch errors other ways as well with no luck. It's like node somehow is not registering with the pi that it's starting a server? I don't know. It's weird.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122946/discussion-between-jason-van-vuren-and-jfriend00).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my issue. It was that I was trying to start the node server from my terminal window within my IDE that is connected to my pi via my mac, instead of using ssh to log into my pi then from that terminal window starting my node server.

All is good now.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess , but maybe try :

```
server.listen('8080', '0.0.0.0', function(){
```

Comment: In my case the `0.0.0.0` was the solution. I was using `localhost` which I believe is mapped to `127.0.0.1` which is only listens for connections on the same machine.